# JQuery ajax call returns 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, iis

I am trying to parse a JSON string upon loading the page but I get the following error in the web dev tools: GET http://ipaddress/CulturalEvents/calWrapper 404 not found (Note: ipaddress is the address for our IIS web server). When I click on the error I get the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 not found.

Here is my index.js

```
var titles = new Array();
var descriptions = new Array();
var count = 0;

// Function to cycle through events on display
function changeText() {
    $('#evtName').html(titles[count]);
    $('#evtDesc').html(descriptions[count]);
    if (count < titles.length - 1) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/CulturalEvents/calWrapper',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(calJSON){

            let eventCheck = 0;
            var today = new Date();
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');

            today = yyyy + mm + dd;
            console.log(today);

            for (let i = 0; i < calJSON.length; i++){
                if (calJSON[i].startDT == today){
                    eventCheck = 1;
                } else {
                    eventCheck = 0;
                }
                if (eventCheck == 1){
                    titles.push(calJSON[i].summary);
                    if (calJSON[i].description == ""){
                        descriptions.push("No description.");
                    } else{
                        descriptions.push(calJSON[i].description)
                    }
                } else {
                    titles.push("No events today.");
                    descriptions.push("If you know of an event that is not displayed feel free to contact the Diversity Equity and Inclusion committee.")
                }
            }
        }
    });

  // Rotate through events
    changeText();
    setInterval(changeText, 10000);

});
```

It can't find my ajax url '/CulturalEvents/calWrapper'. Note I can run this locally and look for the endpoint /calWrapper and it works perfectly fine, but when I run it on the IIS server it stops working.

Here is my app.js as well:

```
    // C library API
const ffi = require('ffi');

// Express app
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

// Send HTML
app.get('/CulturalEvents/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

// Send style
app.get('/CulturalEvents/style.css', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/style.css'));
});

// send JavaScript
app.get('/CulturalEvents/index.js', function (req, res) {
    res.readFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.js'), 'utf8', function(err, contents){
        res.send(contents);
    });
});

// Wrapper function for c library
let wrapper = ffi.Library('./bin/libcalWrapper', {
    'calWrapper': [ 'string', [ 'string' ] ]
});

app.get('/CulturalEvents/calWrapper', function (req, res) {
    var tempStr = JSON.parse(wrapper.calWrapper(__dirname + "/multiculturalcalendar2021.ics"));
    res.send(tempStr);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(__dirname + '/public/index.js');
});
```

Also the directory structure is as follows:

```
CulturalEvents/
    public/
        index.js
        index.html
        style.css
    app.js
    package.json
    web.confi
```

Comment: url:'/CulturalEvents/calWrapper' This will try to find the page relative to the actual page. I guess you mean something like url:'https://ip/CulturalEvents/calWrapper',

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff if I change the url to url:'ip/CulturalEvents/calWrapper' the error changes to GET http://ip/CulturalEvents/ip/CulturalEvents/calWrapper 404

Comment: Ip is only an alias. I do not know what the correct address to your Server is. I can only tell you that you need to put the whole url in there and not just a path

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Yeah I have entered in the correct ip for the server, not just the allias "ip". Still same error as the one mentioned in the OP.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.